# How to break lines in javascript using .join

Tags: javascript, arrays, line-breaks

I have 9 strings "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" in a JavaScript array.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
```

I am printing the value of `arr` using JavaScript alert box.

but, if I use `arr.join(" ")` it is expected like:

```js
a b c d e f g h i
```

but, I want to change the line for every 3rd element.
like:

```js
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The concept of grouping an array into smaller groups is called `chunking`. That can help you to produce an array that looks like `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]...]`. there are libraries on npm to help you with chunking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with `Array#slice`.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
const parts = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3){
  parts.push(arr.slice(i, i + 3).join(' '));
}
console.log(parts.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to chunk arrays:

```js
const chunkSize = 3;

array
  .map((_, i) =>
    i % itemsPerPage
      ? undefined
      : items.slice(
          i,
          Math.floor(i / chunkSize) * chunkSize + chunkSize
        )
  )
      .filter(($) => !!$);
```

So chunk it up and use:

```js
chunkedArray.map((array) => array.join(" ")).join("\n");
```

The `.map` used changes all the arrays inside to `a b c` and then join all of them with a newline character :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that with join by using template literal. e.g:

```js
var arr = ["P613221", "W123456", "ew76879", "GDG767"]

var stringWithQuotes = `'${arr.join(`', '`)}'`

console.log({
  stringWithQuotes,
  query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (${stringWithQuotes})`
})
```

output:

> "P613221', 'W123456', 'ew76879', 'GDG767"